# Elastic search error when using with python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am trying to connect to elastic search using this :

```
app.config['ELASTICSEARCH_URL'] = 'https://localhost:9200/'
```

But showing this error which means elastic search not connected.

**elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionError: ConnectionError(: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused) caused by: NewConnectionError(: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused)**

i searched in stackoverflow they say certificate issue and set ssl set to true. I just want to know how can i connect elastic search to python using the mentioned syntax.

I am made a simple quora clone.Every thing is working.Later i decided to add elastic search into it.First i did connectivity then .

```
def add_to_index(index, model):
if not current_app.elasticsearch:
    return
payload = {}
for field in model.__searchable__:
    payload[field] = getattr(model, field)
current_app.elasticsearch.index(index=index, doc_type=index, id=model.id,
                                body=payload) # shows error here.
```

.While adding new question from ui i used to store it into the database but now i am also pushing it into elastic search along with databse.

while debugging error is displayed as :

```
quora/models.py", line 34, in after_commit
    add_to_index(obj.__tablename__, obj) 
quora/search.py", line 11, in add_to_index # this function i have written above.
    body=payload)**
```

My model

```
class Answer(db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
body = db.Column(db.Text())
timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)
user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable='False')
question_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('question.id'), nullable='False')

def __repr__(self):
    return f"('{self.id}', '{self.body}', '{self.timestamp}')"


class Question(SearchableMixin, db.Model):

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
body = db.Column(db.Text())
timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)
user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable='False')
__searchable__ = ['body']

def __repr__(self):
    return f"('{self.id}', '{self.body}', '{self.timestamp}')"
```

Comment: are you sure there's an Elasticsearch instance running that is listening on 'https://localhost:9200/'?

Comment: yes @AbhishekJaisingh

Comment: you need to explain  your setup in more detail? what app is this?

Comment: can you share snippet where you are making the connection to ES and how

Comment: @DARK_C0D3R sharing